# WordPress plugins and problem with magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write some plugin which adds forms in administration panel and in blog posts. I'm struggling now with magic_quotes.

First I've tried to use magic_quotes_gpc as in clear PHP. But it looks like WordPress ignores this flag and always quotes submitted form contents (at least forms in posts, forms in administration panel are not quoted).

But then I uploaded my plugin to DreamHost and it acts in a different way.

What is the correct way to process submitted form contents in WordPress plugins?

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812128/although-magic-quotes-are-turned-off-still-escaped-strings

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you seem to have a different PHP configuration between (presumably) your development environment and Dreamhost. I assume you would like your plugin to be able to handle both scenarios: magic_quotes on and off. Here's some ideas/thoughts.

- You can't always change php.ini settings at runtime - it depends on the server configuration.
- You can't always change the php.ini either. [On Dreamhost this is possible](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/PHP.ini), but unsupported.
- You can detect if magic_quotes is activated with [ini_get()](http://php.net/ini_get).
- magic_quotes_gpc essentially runs [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes) on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data
- You can perform the inverse operation with [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes).

A common technique is to write a simple wrapper for accessing parameters (GET/POST/COOKIE), such as:

```
function myplugin_param($name)
{
    if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    {
        return stripslashes($_REQUEST[$name]);
    }
    return $_REQUEST[$name];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I know that. Problem is more complicated, I think. I'm processing magic_quotes_gpc in normal way (I'm stripping slashes only, when magic_quotes is on), but on DreamHost every input is quoted.

During my tests on my server with magic_quotes off the input in administrator panel is not quoted, but input in post page is.

Comment: Perhaps the theme you are using is unnecessarily quoting the input. What happens if you activate a different one?

Comment: Exactly the same. My biggest problem is that I'm processing the magic_quotes flag correctly, but on different servers it behaves in different ways. Is there any other flag I should check?